# Is there auto type inferring in Java?

Tags: java, auto

Is there an `auto` variable type in Java like you have in C++?

An example:

```cpp
for ( auto var : object_array)
    std::cout << var << std::endl;

for( auto var : object_array)
    var.do_something_that_only_this_particular_obj_can_do();
```

I know that there is an enhanced for loop in Java, but is there an auto? If not, is there a hack to doing this? I am referring to the new feature in C++11.

Comment: Everything except fundamental types can be assigned to a variable of type `Object`, so for some operations, you can use `Object` where you want `auto`.

Comment: no java has no such variable

Comment: @Zyx2000 : Then, it will use object's `to_string` function, and not the actual object in question, would it not?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: No, it will use the overridden version, if one exists.

Comment: The term you're looking for isn't "auto", it's "type inference". There are quite a few questions about type inference in Java, though they mostly refer to generics, so I'm not sure how to find a duplicate...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Java 10 introduced a `var` identifier which is like C++ `auto`; see [sorrymissjackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037550/).

Prior to Java 10, there was no equivalent to the `auto` keyword. The same loop can be achieved as:

```
for ( Object var : object_array)
  System.out.println(var);
```

Java has local variables, whose scope is within the block where they have been defined. *Similar to C and C++, but there is no auto or register keyword. However, the Java compiler will not allow the usage of a not-explicitly-initialized local variable and will give a compilation error (unlike C and C++ where the compiler will usually only give a warning).* Courtesy: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).

There wasn't any mainstream type-inference in Java like C++ . There was an [RFE](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4459053) but this was closed as "Will not fix". The given was:

> Humans benefit from the redundancy of the type declaration in two ways.
> First, the redundant type serves as valuable documentation - readers do not
> have to search for the declaration of getMap() to find out what type it
> returns. Second, the redundancy allows the programmer to declare the intended
> type, and thereby benefit from a cross check performed by the compiler.

Comment: True, but then would Object not use it's `to_string` function instead of the actual object in question?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac No, method calls are always polymorphic in Java. However, many other things (e.g. overload resolution, or any operation not defined on `Object`) can't be done like this. This is not really a good answer, it only happens to work because the example in the question is weak.

Comment: Then you need to cast it to its original type.

Comment: This question is about the type inference in C++11, not about the old use of `auto` in C and pre-C++11. Your edit is off topic.

Comment: @NoobUnChained : Thats not what I meant, once you type cast it to an `Object`, it will give you Object's `to_string`. Yes, this is a weak example, but ideally, Object is not a full proof alternative, is it?

Comment: I downvoted because this is quite incorrect. Firstly, C, C++, and Java all have identical ideas of local variables. Secondly, it's quite legal in C++ not to explicitly initialize many types, which can safely default-initialize themselves.

Comment: @delnan : Changed the question, does it make it a stronger example?

Comment: " Thats not what I meant, once you type cast it to an Object, it will give you Object's to_string" False. Absolutely 100% false.

Comment: By the way that comment by Gilad Bracha on the closed bug was from 2001. His perception on this might have changed in 12 years!

Comment: Question is about auto type not scope keyword

Comment: "Humans benefit from the redundancy." It's true. Every morning I wake  up and think "how can I make my code more redundant?". Because of the benefits.

Comment: Moreover this answer is obsolete because `var` is a reserved keyword since Java 9.

Comment: The most ridiculous reason to not implement such a handy feature, Now I figure out why my non-developer friends call me typist.

Comment: I may agree that using String in: "String result = somefunction()" may lead to more readable code.
But it is a different thing when it is:
"GrpcMethodFunction<ResuestTimeName, ResultTypeName> method = getMethod()"
And this is a simple one. Other real world examples can get much worse.
I just want to type "var method = getMethod()" and get on with my life.

Answer (score 122):

Might be Java 10 has what you (and I) want, through the `var` keyword.

```
var list = new ArrayList<String>();  // infers ArrayList<String>
var stream = list.stream();          // infers Stream<String>
```

From [JDK Enhancement Proposals 286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)

---

**Update:** Yap, that feature made it into the Java 10 release!

Comment: Ya its an improvement, but that keyword can only work with local variables. Not as powerful as C++ auto type inference

Comment: Minor nit-pick: `var` is not a keyword! From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9): "var is not a keyword, but rather an identifier with special meaning as the type of a local variable declaration". Thus, unlike keywords, there is nothing to stop you calling a variable or a method "var".

Comment: Good point @KlitosKyriacou. Yet, if I imagine to replace 'keyword' with 'identifier' - or even 'identifier with special meaning as the type of a local variable declaration' - the answer would be less clear I think. But yeah, `var` indeed is not in the list of keywords.

Comment: It's not a keyword merely for backward compatibility. Besides the fact that you can have an identifier with this name, var serves a role of a keyword.

Comment: Finally, sad that it took this long. So can we expect type aliasing in another 20 years or so?

Answer (score 28):

Java 7 introduces the [diamond syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond)

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<>(); // Java 7
```

As compared to old java

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>(); // Before Java 7
```

---

The critical reader will notice that this new syntax doesn't help with writing the for loops in the original question. That's correct and fully intentional it seems. See the other answer that cites Oracle's bug database.

Comment: True, but what he (and I) are looking for is something like: `auto integerBox = new Box<Integer>();`, this is usually used for getting a return value from a functions which sometimes can be complexed like `HashMap<String, LinkedList<Operation, Set<Integer>>>`

Comment: That concern is exactly what I addressed after the code samples. The conclusion was that Java doesn't do that, and that's on purpose.

Comment: This addition completely puzzled me when I learned of it. It's completely backwards of what you would expect and provides modest benefit.

Answer (score 20):

In Java 8, you can use lambda type inference to avoid declaring the type.  The analogue to the questioner's examples would be:

```
object_array.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(obj)); 
object_array.forEach(obj -> obj.do_something_that_only_this_particular_obj_can_do());
```

both of which can also be simplified using method references:

```
object_array.forEach(System.out::println); 
object_array.forEach(ObjectType::do_something_that_only_this_particular_obj_can_do);
```

Answer (score 8):

In short, no, there is no auto type.  If all you are doing is printing the value though, you could just refer to the value as an `Object`.

Comment: or computing `hashCode`s, or collecting class names, or... you got the idea ;) The list is short, though. See [Object class' docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (comment meant for beginners, I'm sure you knew it SimonC)

Answer (score 8):

It's not a pure Java solution, however adding a library called [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) will enable the magic below to compile and work very much similar to `auto` keyword in C++

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
for (val s: strList){
    System.out.println(s.length());
}
```